# On running the spring boot application getting the exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-sleuth

While running my spring-boot application getting below exceptions on start up. Not sure what dependency is causing this.

Spring-boot version - 2.3.1
IDE- Intellij

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'braveHttpServerHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpBridgeConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'braveHttpServerHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpTracing' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sleuthSkipPatternProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/instrument/web/SkipPatternConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.SkipPatternProvider]: Factory method 'sleuthSkipPatternProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getBasePath()Ljava/lang/String;
```

It's a multimodule maven project. Please let me know if any additional information is required.

<> Below is the dependency tree after running mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework*

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.5.2:compile
|  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:test
|  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile (optional)
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE:compile
\- io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
   +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
   \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
```

Below is my parent pom.xml

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abnamro.coesd</groupId>
    <artifactId>master-pom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.abnamro.arsr</groupId>
<artifactId>document-search-new</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>document-search-new</name>
<description>Document Search Module</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>es</module>
    <module>earchive</module>
    <module>api</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <java.source>11</java.source>
    <java.target>11</java.target>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <!--<spring.boot.version>2.5.0</spring.boot.version>-->
    <spring.boot.version>2.3.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.cloud.sleuth.version>3.0.4</spring.cloud.sleuth.version>
    <spring.cloud.circuit.breaker>1.0.4.RELEASE</spring.cloud.circuit.breaker>
    <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
    <springdoc.openapi.ui.version>1.4.2</springdoc.openapi.ui.version>
    <dependency.commons.collections.version>4.4</dependency.commons.collections.version>
    <dependency.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</dependency.mapstruct.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>7.9.3</elasticsearch.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</surefire-plugin.version>
    <failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</failsafe-plugin.version>
    <commons.lang3.version>3.11</commons.lang3.version>
    <springfox-swagger2-version>3.0.0</springfox-swagger2-version>
    <joda-time-version>2.10.10</joda-time-version>
    <jakarta.validation.api.version>2.0.2</jakarta.validation.api.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <mapstruct.processor.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.processor.version>
    <jackson-core.version>2.10.2</jackson-core.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.10.2</jackson-databind.version>
    <dependency.junit.jupiter.version>5.8.0-M1</dependency.junit.jupiter.version>
    <javax.validation.version>2.0.1.Final</javax.validation.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.sleuth.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
       
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
       
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client
                </artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

     
    <!-- Uncomment for local usage.-->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.openapi.ui.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.commons.collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakarta.validation.api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.abnamro.arsr</groupId>
        <version>0.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${clean.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>


       
       
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <!-- Use the following configurations to check if there is a failure in compilation -->
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source}</source>
                <target>${java.target}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${dependency.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Check if you added required annotations to the class like @ Service, @ Component

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` sounds very like a version conflict...and [indeed in spring-boot-2.3.1 the method `ManagementServerProperties.getBasePath` is absent](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/web/server/ManagementServerProperties.java).(!) It means something in your "app" is beyond spring-boot.2.3.1! -> `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework*`

Answer (score 2):

For any `NoSuchMethodError` i (offer) bet 99:1  -  it is a version conflict!
;)

The error message is consistent with your statement:

- You use spring-boot:2.3.1.RELEASE
- [There is no such method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/web/server/ManagementServerProperties.java): `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getBasePath()Ljava/lang/String` ..in spring-boot:2.3.1.RELEASE

It means there are some (spring-boot) components > v2.3.1 involved in your autoconfiguration/class path!

A good way to start is (by locating & identifying the version conflict) :

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework*
```

[dependency:tree doc/sample](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html)

(in netbeans you can try the "graph view" of the project pom)

---

**UPDATE: In your case it could even be not a class path conflict, but a property with the key: `management.server.base-path`** (it was introduced ["around" 2.4 only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.4.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/web/server/ManagementServerProperties.java))

Comment: I updated the question with  dependency tree from mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework*

also i checked i do not have management.server.base-path in my properties file.

Comment: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar: **2.5.2** :compile !!! ;)

Comment: i tried lowering the spring-boot-actuator version to 2.3.1.RELEASE but its still not resolved, it gives the same exception. How do I figure out the correct version?

Comment: in spring-boot you normally only set the spring-boot (-parent) version (in a "root pom" (multi-module)), and the rest (all spring-boot dependencies/components are/) is already "managed/magic"...

Comment: (..i.e. you add a `spring-boot-stater-xxx`(dependency) in a "child pom" and *omit* the version)...  in "multi-module", ensure you lower it "everywhere"!...?

Comment: ..if you cannot use the parent-pom (approach): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#using-import

Comment: I have added my parent pom.xml, can you please check it and let me know what to update?

Comment: 1. get rid of the `<version>2.5.6</version>`(spring-boot-starter-actuator) 2.  your pom needs professional and intense re-work (check, validate (delete, try, undelete) every bit of it!;)) (without having presentiment of `master-pom`..)

Comment: It worked. I removed spring-boot-actuator version 2.5.6 and set the spring-boot-parent version only and also removed some unwanted dependencies. Thanks a lot.:)